# Visual Studio Code remote-ssh created too many vscode-server processes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I got too many processes releated to vscode-server on my remote server.
I've used remoted-SSH extension on this server about half a year. And it seems like every time i started a connection, the process will be created and stay alive even if i closed the connection.

```bash
32101 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-34c19751-a5ad-42ba-9941-b3ed5ffaca29.js
32216 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/6a995c4f4cc2ced6e3237749973982e751cb0bf9/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-1fcdaf18-27e1-417c-857e-3244a36d6fcf.js
32287 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-43dcbb33-671b-4310-9e9e-01d9418efe4d.js
32347 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-43dcbb33-671b-4310-9e9e-01d9418efe4d.js
32427 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-43dcbb33-671b-4310-9e9e-01d9418efe4d.js
32462 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-43dcbb33-671b-4310-9e9e-01d9418efe4d.js
32600 pts/56   Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash --init-file /root/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb/out/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration-bash.sh
32687 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/6a995c4f4cc2ced6e3237749973982e751cb0bf9/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-1fcdaf18-27e1-417c-857e-3244a36d6fcf.js
32712 ?        Sl     0:00 /home/codeally/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-43dcbb33-671b-4310-9e9e-01d9418efe4d.js
root@cr-0:~# ps ax | grep -i code | wc -l
371
```

After some connection attempts,the number of processes is still increasing.But i found it could kill the processes when connection quited sometimes.

```bash
root@cr-0:~# ps ax | grep -i code | wc -l
376
root@cr-0:~# ps ax | grep -i code | wc -l
374
```

I wonder if i should just close some of them manually or there are some settings i've missed.
How can I solve this problem?